# connect Oracle 19c database schema/tablespace with Django application

Tags: python, django, database, django-settings, oracle19c

The client provided the single oracle( version 19c ) database in which 2 custom schemas are created and each has a separate tablespace.

I need to connect those schemas/tablespaces with 2 separate Django projects, One schema for each Django project.

**I am unable to connect those schemas/tablespaces with the Django projects. When I run migration all the tables are created under the USERS tablespace of the oracle database.**

I tried with few possible solutions that are available on the internet, such as,

1. Add DEFAULT_TABLESPACE in the settings.py file of each Django project.
2. add class Meta and configure db_tablespace in each class in the models.py file.

Comment: Do the Oracle user accounts (schemas) have their default tablespaces set to the specific ones, or do they both have `USERS` as their defaults?

Comment: Thank you, Alex, your suggestion worked for me.